# Added TForms to TPageControl, how do I notify TForm that it is showing?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe

I have a TPageControl with a number of TTabSheets that contain TForms (or possibly TFrames, but TForms for now).

When a tab comes into view I would like the TForm or TFrame to be notified it has come to the front.  I can't find anything that does that.

I know I can get the Active TTabSheet in the `OnChange` event, so I tried to add this class to the TForm:

```
struct iTab
{
    virtual void DoIt( void ) = 0;
};
```

with the this in the `OnChange`:

```
  ICPTab *tab = dynamic_cast<ICPTab *>( sheet->Controls[ 0 ] );
```

Thinking I could use RTTI to get the `iTab` pointer and call `DoIt()` from the 
And I get the warning:

```
[BCC32 Warning] Unit1.h(18): W8130 Interface 'IPTab' does not derive from IUnknown. (Interfaces should derive from IUnknown) 
[BCC32 Warning] MainWindow.cpp(612): W8131 Casting Delphi style class 'TControl' to an interface. Use 'System::interface_cast<ICPTab>(cls)' instead
```

I am not interested in getting all of IUnknown just so that the form can use an interface.

I can get the TFrame or TForm pointer using:

```
  TForm *tab = dynamic_cast<TForm *>( sheet->Controls[ 0 ] );
```

but can't call a non TForm method with this pointer.  Would it be ok to call the `Activate()` method?

So how do I notify the TForm or TFrame that it is now showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the following code:

```
  void __fastcall TgMainWindow::mPageControlChange( TObject* Sender )
  {
     NOT_USED( Sender );
     TTabSheet* sheet = mPageControl->ActivePage;

     if ( sheet->ControlCount > 0 )
     {
        // form or frame, we will attempt to call the OnActivate method
        TForm* form = dynamic_cast<TForm *>( sheet->Controls[ 0 ] );

        if ( form == NULL )
        {
           ShowMessageDlg( this, L"Programming Error: Initial child on tabsheet must be a TForm", mtError, TMsgDlgButtons( ) << mbOK );
        }
        else
        {
           if ( form->OnActivate != NULL )
           {
              form->OnActivate( this );
           }
           else
           {
              ShowMessageDlg( this, L"Programming Error: From must have an OnActivate event", mtError, TMsgDlgButtons( ) << mbOK );
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Since a form on a tabsheet never has its OnActivate method called, this works quite well.

*note: the method sample is not complete, there is no call to OnDeactivate*

Comment: Use the `TPageControl::OnChanging` event to call the active sheet's `TForm::OnDeactivate` event.  Or keep track of the last active Sheet/Form so the `OnChange` event knows which `TForm` to deactivate before calling `OnActivate`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to derive `iTab` from `IUnknown` (or `IInterface`) or order to use it as an interface correctly.  The compiler warning even hints that you can use `interface_cast` to extract an interface from a Delphi-style (aka `TObject`-derived) object.  Alternatively use `TObject::GetInterface()` instead.

Otherwise, if you just want to call methods of your custom TForm class, then just type-cast the child control pointer from your TTabSheet to your actual TForm-derived class:

```
TMyForm *tab = dynamic_cast<TMyForm *>( sheet->Controls[ 0 ] );
if( tab != NULL ) tab->DoSomething();
```

Or:

```
static_cast<TMyForm *>( sheet->Controls[ 0 ] )->DoSomething();
```

Comment: so basically I can't use standard C++ with a TObject based class.  Deriving from a TUnknown, which then requires extra functions and a GUID, are not what I want for this simple use.

Comment: You can use C++ code with Delphi-based classes, you just have to use it correctly since Delphi has a different object model than C++.